# Tensorflow value error: Cannot feed value of shape (96, 50, 50) for Tensor u'InputData/X:0', which has shape '(?, 50, 50, 1)'

Tags: python, deep-learning, google-colaboratory, conv-neural-network

I am new to TensorFlow and python. I am trying to run a code for lung cancer detection using CNN. Here is the script: I'm trying to train a CNN model. When I use `model.fit` while training I am getting an error

```
    from tflearn.layers.core import input_data, dropout, fully_connected
from tflearn.layers.conv import conv_2d, max_pool_2d
from tflearn.layers.estimator import regression
from tflearn.data_preprocessing import ImagePreprocessing
from tflearn.data_augmentation import ImageAugmentation

img_prep = ImagePreprocessing()
img_prep.add_featurewise_zero_center()
img_prep.add_featurewise_stdnorm()

img_aug = ImageAugmentation()
img_aug.add_random_flip_leftright()
img_aug.add_random_rotation(max_angle=25.)
img_aug.add_random_blur(sigma_max=3.)

network = input_data(shape=[None, 50, 50, 1],
                     data_preprocessing=img_prep,
                     data_augmentation=img_aug)
network = conv_2d(network, 50, 3, activation='relu')
network = max_pool_2d(network, 2)
network = conv_2d(network, 64, 3, activation='relu')
network = conv_2d(network, 64, 3, activation='relu')
network = max_pool_2d(network, 2)
network = fully_connected(network, 512, activation='relu')
network = dropout(network, 0.5)
network = fully_connected(network, 2, activation='softmax')
network = regression(network, optimizer='adam',
                     loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                     learning_rate=0.001)

model = tflearn.DNN(network, tensorboard_verbose=0, checkpoint_path='nodule-classifier.tfl.ckpt')


model.fit(X_train_images, Y_train_labels, n_epoch=100, shuffle=True, validation_set=(X_val_images, Y_val_labels),
          show_metric=True, batch_size=96, snapshot_epoch=True, 
          run_id='noduleclassifier')

model.save("nodule-classifier.tfl")
print("Network trained and saved as nodule-classifier.tfl!")
```

I'm trying to train a CNN model. When I use `model.fit` while training I am getting an error -->

```
ValueErrorTraceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-60-e6a88471dbf1> in <module>()
      5 model.fit(X_train_images, Y_train_labels, n_epoch=100, shuffle=True, validation_set=(X_val_images, Y_val_labels),
      6           show_metric=True, batch_size=96, snapshot_epoch=True,
----> 7           run_id='noduleclassifier')
      8 
      9 # Save model when training is complete to a file

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

/tensorflow-1.15.2/python2.7/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.pyc in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1154                 'Cannot feed value of shape %r for Tensor %r, '
   1155                 'which has shape %r' %
-> 1156                 (np_val.shape, subfeed_t.name, str(subfeed_t.get_shape())))
   1157           if not self.graph.is_feedable(subfeed_t):
   1158             raise ValueError('Tensor %s may not be fed.' % subfeed_t)

ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (96, 50, 50) for Tensor u'InputData/X:0', which has shape '(?, 50, 50, 1)'
```

[error_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNS2I.png)

link to original code --> [link](https://github.com/swethasubramanian/LungCancerDetection/blob/master/notebooks/LungCancerDetection.ipynb)

Can anyone help me solve this please??

Comment: Hello! Welcome to SO! Please go through [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Going by just the title, `numpy.squeeze` may help you getting rid of that extra dimension with shape 1.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more please

Comment: What part do you not understand?

Comment: how to use 'numpy.squeeze'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The model expects a tensor of dimesnion 4.
You have to add a fourth dimension to the training data. 
Use

```
X_train_images = np.expand_dims(X_train_images, axis=-1)
```

To expand the dimensions and np.squeeze to reduce the dimensions

Comment: Expand dimension only. Don't reduce it. You didn't do it properly. When you do it correctly, the data will have shape (?, 50,50,1), since you have 96 data, (96,50,50,1)

Comment: Yeah, I got that. Now I get the shape as (90, 50, 50, 1) when I use `X_train_images.shape` But when I  begin the training it still shows the same error.

Comment: Is there a problem with how I am feeding my data to the network using `input_data` ?